# How to retrieve value from this object?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Using php, I trying to get a particular coupon.

```
require_once './lib/Stripe.php';
Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_SK);
$response = Stripe_Coupon::retrieve('coupon id here');
print_r($response);
```

print_r($response); gave me the object below. My question is how can retrieve the [id] from the object? Thanks for helping

```
Stripe_Coupon Object
(
    [_apiKey:protected] => sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [_values:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10percent
            [created] => 1395914393
            [percent_off] => 10
            [amount_off] => 
            [currency] => 
            [object] => coupon
            [livemode] => 
            [duration] => repeating
            [redeem_by] => 
            [max_redemptions] => 
            [times_redeemed] => 2
            [duration_in_months] => 12
            [valid] => 1
       )
)
```

Comment: You can try `$response->_values->id` or something like that.

Comment: This does not work. thanks for the input though

Comment: `$response->_values[0]` ? Just try stuff out. It's located inside _values, which is an array.

Comment: `$response->id` will work. Stripe objects are more complex than they what you see when you print them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is using the PHP magic __get method. You should just be able to use:

```
$id = $response->id;
```

If you go through source you see the object eventually comes down to the Stripe_Object class. Source here:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/Stripe/Object.php